# Different View for Landscpe and portrait

Tags: ios5, orientation, xcode4.2

I have 2 button .In first button I used separate view for landscape and portrait and for the second button I use only one view for both portrait and landscape. But when I click on button 2, it get load  on portrait view then orientation to the landscape mode it load the first buttons landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u used CGRect class for button1 views.
use separate functions for Landscape mode and portrait mode.
I think this will be useful for you.